When trying to implement a uniswapv3 example contract, I am not able to compile it
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later
pragma solidity =0.7.6;
pragma abicoder v2;

import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/libraries/TickMath.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol';
import '../libraries/TransferHelper.sol';
import '../interfaces/INonfungiblePositionManager.sol';
import '../base/LiquidityManagement.sol';

contract LiquidityExamples is IERC721Receiver {
    address public constant DAI = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;
    address public constant USDC = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48;

    uint24 public constant poolFee = 3000;

    INonfungiblePositionManager public immutable nonfungiblePositionManager;

    /// @notice Represents the deposit of an NFT
    struct Deposit {
        address owner;
        uint128 liquidity;
        address token0;
        address token1;
    }

    /// @dev deposits[tokenId] => Deposit
    mapping(uint256 => Deposit) public deposits;

    constructor(
        INonfungiblePositionManager _nonfungiblePositionManager
    ) {
        nonfungiblePositionManager = _nonfungiblePositionManager;
    }

    // Implementing `onERC721Received` so this contract can receive custody of erc721 tokens
    function onERC721Received(
        address operator,
        address,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes calldata
    ) external override returns (bytes4) {
        // get position information

        _createDeposit(operator, tokenId);

        return this.onERC721Received.selector;
    }

    function _createDeposit(address owner, uint256 tokenId) internal {
        (, , address token0, address token1, , , , uint128 liquidity, , , , ) =
            nonfungiblePositionManager.positions(tokenId);

        // set the owner and data for position
        // operator is msg.sender
        deposits[tokenId] = Deposit({owner: owner, liquidity: liquidity, token0: token0, token1: token1});
    }
}

This is the contract im trying to implement, the error im getting is
Error HH404: File ../libraries/TransferHelper.sol, imported from contracts/LiquidityExamples.sol, not found.

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH404 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces

However, when I change the .. to the absolute path to their respective locations, I get this compilations error
CompilerError: Stack too deep when compiling inline assembly: Variable headStart is 1 slot(s) too deep inside the stack.

Error HH600: Compilation failed

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH600 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces

I dont know what to do, any help would be greatly welcomed~!
Here is the official uniswap documentation with the example I mentioned above https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/guides/providing-liquidity/setting-up
